# How to bind secured PHP source code running inside Docker to a specific IP or MAC address?

Tags: php, docker, security, ioncube

There are tools like [ioncube](https://www.ioncube.com/) or [php encoder](https://www.sourceguardian.com), which make it possible to restrict PHP source code usage to specific IP addresses or MAC addresses. In theory it works perfectly fine, when the source code is deployed on a server (or servers) with specific static address. But I do not understand, how to secure source code, when it is deployed, using tools like Docker.

The problem is that Docker dynamically assigns IP and MAC addresses to running containers, so it seems like such tools as ioncube or php encoder can not work in this environment. Am I right or is it still possible to bind dockerized source code to specific addresses?

Comment: Why not asking ionCube support directly?

Comment: @Jay Blanchard. Have you seen the thread, that you attached? It has no approved answers. The topic starter says, that the provided solution does not work

Comment: @AmigoJack. Just because the whole solution may relate to Docker configuration

Comment: How are you running your containers? Are they on a server for which you can restrict IP's?

Comment: @Jay Blanchard. Yes, containers are running on a server with ristricted IP address

Comment: If the server is restricted and is set up as a gateway to your Docker containers you should not need to address whitelisting in your specific containers.

Comment: @Jay Blanchard. Can you, please, a bit elaborate on this? What do you mean by addressing whitelisting?

Comment: @Jay Blanchard. And if I bind the source code to the static IP of my host machine, but deploy this code inside Dockers, do you mean that it should work without any specific configurations?

Comment: Bind the source code? Only those with access to the server would have access to the source code.

Comment: @Yes. This is what these encoding tools like ioncube and PHP encoder do. They make it possible to run the source code on a specific server with specific IP address

Comment: Have you seen this https://blog.ioncube.com/2017/09/22/ioncube-docker-support/?